# How to vectorize stroke in Sketch App?

Tags: vector, shapes, sketch-app, stroke

I'm trying to get similar effect as illustrator. How can I get inside border vector in Sketch App?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't give the top rectangle a border, instead use Fills.
2. Select all objects
3. Click on Union ( **Layer>Combine>Union**) or **⌥⌘U**